# change series to be dataframe and use number inside label as index of dataframe, the other part as column name

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a series it is like:

```
{lag1mid_quoteDiff:  1.51
lag1TradeDirection: 2.12
lag2mid_quoteDiff:  1.53
lag2TradeDirection: 2.18
lag3mid_quoteDiff:  1.59
lag3TradeDirection: 2.10}
```

I need a dataframe as to have two columns, lagmid_quoteDiff and lagTradeDirection, with 3 rows, index as 1, 2, 3:

```
  lagmid_quoteDiff lagTradeDirection
1     1.51              2.12
2     1.53              2.18
3     1.59              2.10
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You should parse the column names and then reconstruct your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `crosstab` after modify the series

```
s = pd.Series(data)
s1 = s.index.str.extract('(\d+)')[0]
out = pd.crosstab(index = s1, columns = s.index.str.replace('(\d+)',''), values = s.values, aggfunc = 'sum')
out
col_0  lagTradeDirection  lagmid_quoteDiff
0                                         
1                   2.12              1.51
2                   2.18              1.53
3                   2.10              1.59
```

Comment: @PaulP  if this is work , would you like accept it ? check mark at the left .

Comment: Thanks a lot, I am very fresh on the stackoverflow and just got how to accept an answer, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

If you can ensure that the order of your dictionary entries is consistent:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"lag1mid_quoteDiff":  1.51,
"lag1TradeDirection": 2.12,
"lag2mid_quoteDiff":  1.53,
"lag2TradeDirection": 2.18,
"lag3mid_quoteDiff":  1.59,
"lag3TradeDirection": 2.10}

data = np.array(list(data.values()))
df = pd.DataFrame(data.reshape(-1, 2), columns=["lagmid_quoteDiff", "lagTradeDirection"])

print(df)
   lagmid_quoteDiff  lagTradeDirection
0              1.51               2.12
1              1.53               2.18
2              1.59               2.10
```

If you can not guarantee the order of your dictionary entries, try this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {"lag1mid_quoteDiff":  1.51,
"lag1TradeDirection": 2.12,
"lag2mid_quoteDiff":  1.53,
"lag2TradeDirection": 2.18,
"lag3mid_quoteDiff":  1.59,
"lag3TradeDirection": 2.10}

df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[0]).melt()
df = (df["variable"].str.extract(r"(?P<lag_n>\d+)(?P<type>\w+)")
      .join(df)
      .pivot(index="lag_n", columns="type", values="value")
      .rename_axis(columns=None))

print(df)
       TradeDirection  mid_quoteDiff
lag_n                               
1                2.12           1.51
2                2.18           1.53
3                2.10           1.59
```

Answer (score 0):

Not quite as elegant, but gets the job done:

```py
series = pd.Series({
    'lag1mid_quoteDiff':  1.51,
    'lag1TradeDirection': 2.12,
    'lag2mid_quoteDiff':  1.53,
    'lag2TradeDirection': 2.18,
    'lag3mid_quoteDiff':  1.59,
    'lag3TradeDirection': 2.10
})

unpack = {}

for k, v in series.iteritems():
    re_match = re.match(r'(lag)(\d+)(.*)', k)
    try:
        index_num = int(re_match.group(2))
        col = re_match.group(1)+re_match.group(3)
        if unpack.get(col):
            unpack[col][index_num] = v
        else:
            unpack[col] = {index_num: v}
    except Exception as e:
        raise ValueError(f"Provided key is incorrect format: {k}")

df = pd.DataFrame(unpack)
```

```
   lagmid_quoteDiff  lagTradeDirection
1              1.51               2.12
2              1.53               2.18
3              1.59               2.10
```